# Material Design Icon - supported upstream

Tags: icons, material-design

Roughly two years ago (2017) we decided to use the material design icons which are available here: https://github.com/google/material-design-icons

Unfortunately this repo does not get any updates any more. Last commit is from January 2018.

There are several forks, but AFAIK none got the "Bandwagon effect".

Where can I get supported material design icons?

Comment: Despite the lack of recent activity in the repo, the icons referenced in your question are still the official material icon set by Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fork receives updates and looks well maintained: https://github.com/jossef/material-design-icons-iconfont

Answer (score 0):

You can look for supported icons on MaterializeCSS and material.io official site as they keep updating documentations with new releases.

Here are related links:

> 1) https://materializecss.com/icons.html.
>   2) https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-web.
>   3) https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline